# Android: Need an idea which to use: Service, Thread, AsyncTask or something ese

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I am struggling of what technologies to use for my current problem.

I have an application required to load every pages of the pdf to an image an display to the screen. The time to load the pages to an image file can be quite long. These images generated from pdf will be displayed on imageView.

I am wonder will the Service be over killed or do I just you either the AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **service**

As **Docs** says :

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.
>   Another application component can start a service and it will continue
>   to run in the background even if the user switches to another
>   application.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask should only be used for operations that take quite few seconds.

AsyncTasks are executed serially on a single background thread (from API 11). So long running worker can block others.

Consider to use service, still you'll need threading (by default service runs in the UI thread).